# Can't I define an instance of an ERC20 inside the constructor?

Tags: solidity

Recently, I was trying to mint Dai using Compound protocol. The function originally looked like this...

```
IERC20 public underlying;
ICERC20 public cToken;
...

constructor(address _daiAddress, address _cdaiAddress) public payable {
        underlying = IERC20(_daiAddress);
        cToken = ICERC20(_cdaiAddress);
}

function mintCDai(uint _numberOfDaiToSupply) private { 
        require(underlying.approve(address(cToken), _numberOfDaiToSupply), "Failed to approve sending token");
        require(cToken.mint(_numberOfDaiToSupply) == 0, "Failed to mint cToken");
        ...
    }
```

However, MetaMask kept telling me the instance would keep failing. Eventually, after changing the token instances to be defined inside the function, like such

```
IERC20 public underlying;
ICERC20 public cToken;
...
function mintCDai(uint _numberOfDaiToSupply) private {     
        underlying = IERC20(0x5592EC0cfb4dbc12D3aB100b257153436a1f0FEa);
        cToken = ICERC20(0x6D7F0754FFeb405d23C51CE938289d4835bE3b14);   
        require(underlying.approve(address(cToken), _numberOfDaiToSupply), "Failed to approve sending token");
        require(cToken.mint(_numberOfDaiToSupply) == 0, "Failed to mint cToken");
        ...
    }
```

It allowed the transaction to go through. But shouldn't I be able to define the Erc within the constructor so functions will have access to it?

Comment: It is unlikely that MetaMask would be the reason of failing, but there is some `require()` tripped or `revert` thrown. I suggest you write some unit tests for your code,or just let MetaMask to broadcast the transaction, so you wil see the actual revert message. MetaMask currently does not give you the reason of revert.